# how to mock HTTPcontext using Moq

Tags: asp.net, .net, moq

My company has its own SDK which contains the following class:

```
public class SharePointContext(System.Web.HttpContext context)
{

}
```

How can i use Moq to mock the HttpContext to be passed in argument? The sample from internet using HttpContextBase and obviously it will throw an error since you cannot assign concrete class with an abstract class.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For the latest Moq, something like this should work. Seems that Moq requires an abstract class or interface, or atleast a class that is not sealed. All of which make it difficult to mock `HttpContext`.

```
//class that returns all the mock objects you need..
public static class MockHelpers
{
   public static HttpContextBase GetFakeContext()
   {
       var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
       //we need these for our context 
       var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
       var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
       var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
       var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();


       context.Setup(ct => ct.Request).Returns(request.Object);
       context.Setup(ct => ct.Response).Returns(response.Object);
       context.Setup(ct => ct.Session).Returns(session.Object);
       context.Setup(ct => ct.Server).Returns(server.Object);

       return context.Object;
   }
}
```

You then use it like this:

```
public class SharePointContext(MockHelpers.GetFakeContext());
```

Comment: mate.. as i said i have tried the same approach as you gave. it is complaining about cannot assign HttpContextBase to HttpContext

Comment: @gideon.. HttpContext is concrete class. you cannot mock the concrete class.  you can only mock the either abstract or interface classes.

Comment: @user384080 yep you're right I didn't realize. If it's your code  you could probably change it. You may have a typo though? :`public **class** SharePointContext(System.Web.HttpContext context)` Is it a method.

Comment: Injecting HttpContext is not very helpful as you can't mock HttpContext without a toll like TypeMock. Like @gideon suggests you should inject HttpContextBase, which is mockable and use HttpContextWrapper when you need to use the real HttpContext. You can read more about it here for example http://splinter.com.au/httpcontext-vs-httpcontextbase-vs-httpcontext